# A Java lib that has a utility for finding the least common multiple of a set of integers

Tags: java, lcm

I would like to find the least common multiple of a set of integers. Does a numerical Java library that does this exist? Please provide a link to it.

Comment: None that I could find, but it's really easy to code this for yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201860/how-to-find-gcf-lcm-on-a-set-of-numbers

Comment: I must be getting old, but I long for the 'good old days' in which programmers would try to crack a problem themselves before reaching for a 'plug-n-play' API.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/4202114/579580

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, children of nowadays have no minerals :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson ... in the good old days people would happily find and copy other peoples work.

Comment: Cracking a problem yourself is considered bad practice these days :) NIH, reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Orbital library](http://symbolaris.com/orbital/index.html) has an LCM method.  Here is the [javadoc](http://symbolaris.com/orbital/Orbital-doc/api/orbital/math/MathUtilities.html).