# LCM (lowest common multiple) in Java

Tags: java

I need help with this loop. One of my course assignments is to make a LCM program.

```
Sample output:
(8,12) LCM is 24
(4,3) LCM is 12
(5,10,20) LCM is 20
(18,24,52) LCM is 936
(12,10,26) LCM is 780
(99,63,24) LCM is 5544
(62,16,24) LCM is 1488
```

I have this so far for 2 numbers but I'm not sure how to do 3 numbers. We're supposed to use methods on other classes so this is what I have for the LCM class.

```
public class LCM {
    private int n, x, s = 1, t = 1;

    public LCM()
    {
        n = 0;
        x = 0;
        s = 1;
        t = 1;
    }
    public int lcmFind(int i, int y) {
        for (n = 1;; n++) {
            s = i * n;
            for (x = 1; t < s; x++) {
                t = y * x;
            }
            if (s == t)
                break;
        }
        return (s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a general word of advice, use more obvious variable names rather than just single letters.  It can get complicated very quickly otherwise.

Comment: I won't read that code. For the reason stated above.

Comment: Rather than `for (...) { t = y * x; } if (s == t) break;`, simply do `if (y % s == 0) break;`.

Comment: Please don't omit a `for` loop condition then put an `if ... break` at the end of the loop block.  That's confusing for those that follow and have to read/maintain the code.  Ditto on the variable names.  No, homework code won't be maintained, but it will be *read* by a grader, and it's better to get good habits started right away.

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201860/how-to-find-gcf-lcm-on-a-set-of-numbers

Answer (score 3):

I found this [link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2016/07/how-to-calculate-gcf-and-lcm-of-two-numbers-in-java-example.html) and I guess this is most simple and clean solution:

```
/**
* Calculate Lowest Common Multiplier
*/
public static int LCM(int a, int b) {
    return (a * b) / GCF(a, b);
}

/**
* Calculate Greatest Common Factor
*/
public static int GCF(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return (GCF(b, a % b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get LCM of 3+ numbers you can use your method `lcmFind` in following way:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int c = 5;
LCM l = new LCM();
int lcm = l.lcmFind(l.lcmFind(a, b), c);
```

Reccomendations:

- Make `n`,`x`, `s` and `t` variables local in `lcmFind`. Because you need them ONLY in `lcmFind` method and you need to reset their values in every invocation of `lcmFind`.
- Make your `lcmFind` method static. You don't need to instantiate new object in order to calc lcm. This way you can use it like `LCM.lcmFind(3,4)`, or even better rename method and use something like `LCM.find(3,4)`.

**EDIT**
If you need to make method that takes variable number of argument you should check [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). So you'll get something like:

```
public int lcmFind(int.. args) {
    // args is actually array of ints.
    // calculate lcm of all values in array.
    // usage: lcmFind(1,4) or lcmFind(1,5,6,3)
}
```

You can use your first version of `lcmFind` that takes 2 arguments and calculate lcm of many values using it.

**EDIT 2**
If you need only 2 and 3-args version of `lcmFind` than you can just add 3-arg version:

```
public int lcmFind(int a, int b, int c) {
    return lcmFind(lcmFind(a, b), c); 
}
```

Comment: My teacher is very strict. He's not gonna allow that. He wants it like lcmFind(a, b, c) using overloading.

Comment: We haven't learned arrays yet. We're just starting methods and classes. Still learning. I just need help with finding the LCM for 2 and 3 numbers.

Comment: @GarrettOutlaw I've updated my answer. You can just create 3-arg version of `lcmFind` that uses 2-arg version.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public int lcm(int... a) {
    for (int m = 1;; m++) {
        int n = a.length;
        for (int i : a) {
            if (m % i != 0) {
                break;
            }
            if (--n == 0) {
                return m;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b){
    return (b == 0) ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}

public static int gcd(int... args){
    int r = args[0];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < args.length - 1)
        r = gcd(r,args[++i]);
    return r;
}

public static int lcm(int a, int b){
    return a * b / gcd(a,b);
}

public static int lcm(int... args){
    int r = args[0];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < args.length - 1)
        r = lcm(r,args[++i]);
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int  getLCM(int a,int b)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    if(a<b)
    {
        x=a;
         y=b;   
    }
    else
    {
         x=b;
         y=a;   
    }
    int i=1;
    while(true)
    {

        int x1=x*i;
        int y1=y*i;
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
        if(x1==y*j)
        {
            return x1;
        }
        }

        i++;
    }



}
```

Comment: I would like to encourage you to use two loops with proper increments rather than while(true).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the answer already, since it's an old post. still posting my answer. Below is the code to find the LCM for an array:

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayEqualAmz {
    static int lcm =1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int [] arr = new int[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("lcm = "+lcm(arr));

    }

    // find the factor
    public static int divisor(int x[]){
        Arrays.sort(x);
        int num=0;
        for(int i=x.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            if(x[i] != 1 )
            num=x[i];
        }
        for(int j=2; j<=num; j++){
            if(num%j==0){
            return j;}
        }
        return num;
    }

    //finding the lcm
    public static int lcm(int arr[]){
        while(true){

        int j = divisor(arr);
        if(j==0){break;}
        lcm = lcm*j;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i]%j==0){
            arr[i] = arr[i]/j;}
        System.out.print(arr[i]+",");
        }
        System.out.println( " factor= "+lcm);
        return lcm(arr);
        }
        return lcm;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     int n1 = 72, n2 = 120, lcm;

    // maximum number between n1 and n2 is stored in lcm
    lcm = (n1 > n2) ? n1 : n2;

    // Always true
    while(true)
    {
        if( lcm % n1 == 0 && lcm % n2 == 0 )
        {
            System.out.printf("The LCM of %d and %d is %d.", n1, n2, lcm);
            break;
        }
        ++lcm;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re use the same function written for lcm of two numbers. Just pass one of the arguments as follows:

The function code can be like this:

```
public static int lcm(int num1,int num2) {
        boolean flag = false;
        int lcm = 0;
        for(int i= 1;!flag; i++){
           flag = (num1 < num2)?(num2*i)%num1==0:(num1*i)%num2==0;
           lcm = num1<num2?num2*i:num1*i;
        }
        return lcm;
    }
```

Call the function like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("lcm "+lcm(lcm(20,80),40));
    }
```