# How to find Lowest Common Multiple in java

Tags: java, int

Can anyone help me, I have no idea how to find the lowest common multiple.

For example with the numbers 4 and 5 which is 20. This is what I want to achieve in code.

Thank you

Comment: possible dublicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201860/how-to-find-gcf-lcm-on-a-set-of-numbers

Comment: Hope this link will help you : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201860/how-to-find-gcf-lcm-on-a-set-of-numbers

Comment: Also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple

Comment: A simple web search would give you hundred of links for this. However, the real fun is to simply trying to code the logic yourself. Where is that you hitting a block when trying to code the algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't the best solution but it is a solution see the links in the replies for better solutions

```
b = 4;
a = 5;

for(int i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
    if(i*a % b == 0)
        return abs(i*a);
}
```

Thanks iamnotmaynard for the suggestion

Comment: You could also do up to `i <= b` and remove the line `return a*b;` (also, it should use the absolute values, in case one is negative).