# LCM of a range of number in JAVA

Tags: java

is there any more efficient way to get the LCM of a range of numbers in JAVA without using the BigInteger..?

I tried with the BigInteger and it worked, but i am looking for more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Did you check this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4201860/1089811

Answer (score 0):

```
public static long lcm(long[] input) {
    long result = input[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < input.length; i++)
        result = lcm(result, input[i]);
    return result;
}
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4202114/1433665).