# I am facing an error in the following java code can anyone help me out

Tags: java, runtime-error

```java
class Solution {
  
    long  maxGcd(int  N) {
        long  a = (N * (N - 1))/ gcd(N,N-1);
        long  b = ((N-2)*(N-3))/ gcd(N-2,N-3);
        long  c = (a*b)/ gcd(a,b);
        long  num = N*(N-1);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = N - 2; i >= 1; i--) {
            if (gcd(num, i) == 1) {
                num *= i;
                count++;
            }
            if (count == 2) break;
        }
        return  Math.max(c, num);
    }

    long  gcd(long x, long y)
    {
        if(y==0)
        return x;
        return gcd(y,x*y);
    }
}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

I think I am getting this error because if, at some point, b=0  then c will be undefined. I tried changing it to

```java
if(b!=0){
    long c =(a*b)/gcd(a,b)
```

but after running it, gives an error saying

```
prog.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        return  Math.max(c, num);
```

Can anyone help me with the solution of this error?

Given an integer N. Find maximum LCM (Least Common Multiple) that can be obtained from four numbers less than or equal to N.
Note: Duplicate numbers can be used.

Example 1:

Input:
N = 4
Output: 12
Explanation:
The four numbers can be [4,4,3,2] or
[4,4,4,3], etc. It can be shown that 12 is
the maximum LCM of four numbers that can
be obtained from numbers less than or equal
to 4.

I have tried the above problem but it was giving me unexpected error.

Comment: `return gcd(y, x % y)` in `long  gcd(long x, long y)` will do the trick. However, your current code results in a divide by 0 error. For calculating GCD and LCM look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201860/how-to-find-gcd-lcm-on-a-set-of-numbers

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting this right, it looks like there is a problem with your function "gcd": the recursive loop will never end

Comment: This is not really an answer, more a hint/idea. These kind of message should be placed as a comment to the question, not as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you divide some digit by 0  it will throw an error known as : **java.lang.ArithmeticException**

> Solution

1. try, catch block
2. in catch block you can show msg to user ("Number cannot be divided by 0")